# Format (spread) text in DefaultListCellRenderer

Tags: java, string, swing, format, jlist

I have a list of expences that looks like this :
[My List](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54830465/Upload/IMG)

I would like the elements of the list to appear as if formatted with \t :

```
PRODUCT NAME      PRICE      DATE
PRODUCT NAME      PRICE      DATE
```

ect. I created DefaultListCellRenderer but I don't know how to implement this formatting.. If it's not doable, than at least how do I center the elements?

My DefaultListCellRenderer looks like this at the moment :

```
     private class MyListRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {  

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public Component getListCellRendererComponent( JList<?> list,  
                Object value, int index, boolean isSelected,  
                boolean cellHasFocus )  
        {  
        Component c = super.getListCellRendererComponent( list, value, index,  
                    isSelected, cellHasFocus );  


            Color czerwony = new Color(205, 16, 26);    
                setForeground(czerwony);

                return(this);       
        }


    }
```

Comment: Myself, I'd use a JTable for the display of tabular data. Otherwise you're forcing yourself to use ugly monospace fonts and kludgy code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shoot, I'll make my comment an answer: use a JTable to display tabular data since it excels at this and was built for this. Otherwise if you want to create your own kludge of a Table via a JList, you'll be forced to use mono-spaced fonts and code that can easily break if one item of data exceeds the expected width of that column.

If you have restrictions on why you can't or are not allowed to use this, then please by all means share this with us.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: if you lived in Chicago you could up-vote it several times.

Comment: +1, `Shoot, I'll make my comment an answer:` - Its nice to have an answer the OP can accept.